# How do I change the select option value contents using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm not good at javascript but I tried this...
I'm trying to make an option for a user to switch to another page after searching for an item.
The user for example will searches for a Mercedes under cars section then the options value can change to the Mercedes links page as well as can change to GMC links page is the user searches for gmc. This code seems not to work.
Below is the code:

```
<div class="all" id="note">
    Some content will be posted here...
</div>
<select id="marketing" onChange="window.open(this.value)" multiple>
  <option value="1">cars</option>
  <option value="2">houses</option>
  <option value="3">Promotion</option>
</select> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  var cars = ['mercedes']
  $('#marketing').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() == '1'){
    if cars[0] ==='mercedes';{
      $(this).val() == "http://www.cars.com/mercedes";
    }
    }
  });
```

Comment: What is `i` in your code?

Comment: sorry, meant to be [0]

Comment: `window.open(this.value)` will try to open URLs like: `1`, `2`, and `3`, none of which are URLs.

Comment: @scot, this is only part of the code. I want it to work first then add more. So is the user clicks on cars, under that the options will be variable depending on the input. In this case, its mercedes or if the user searched for bentley, then the link changes, but still uder the value='1'. I just don't know how to code it.

Comment: maybe using form ?

Comment: @Swati, its an sms based app feature. I don't know how form will do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
var cars = ['mercedes']
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("marketing").value;
        var companey = document.getElementById('companies').value;
        console.log(x + companey);
        if (x == 1 && companey == "mercedes") {
            var url = 
            window.open("http://www.cars.com/mercedes" , '_blank');//for new tab
            //for same tab
            //window.open('http://www.cars.com/mercedes');
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!this is a working sample hope this will help>
    <div class="all" id="note">
    Some content will be posted here...    <br />
        <input type="text" id="companies">mercedes</input>

</div>
<select id="marketing" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="1">cars</option>
  <option value="2">houses</option>
  <option value="3">Promotion</option>
</select> 
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much@Touseef Ahmed Awan. This works as I need